# Animation are moving the box collider and not the object in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

Hi I'm new to unity & C# And i have this project were i have to make the door open when ever you are inside the cube(trigger) and close when you are outside the trigger But I haven't got to that part yet because when I created the animation I had a problem . More info Below

Watch this video  I recorded everything I did to make the animation step by step (please watch to understand my problem)
https://youtu.be/7l5FeNrMb9g

As you can see in the video I created 4 clips (close, opening, open, closing)

[image: the animations]

and animated everything in the video . But the problem is the object (The door) are not moving when I start the game the only thing that moving I think it is the box collider watch this!
https://youtu.be/ZCI0i6s9Mos

I have this problem for 2 days its really annoying me And by the way i'm following a YouTube tutorial this the video I'm following

https://youtu.be/13jceft_0PQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Door` is marked as a [**static** `GameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StaticObjects.html)!

[image]

Among other things it is therefore used for [static batching](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DrawCallBatching.html), [static lighting](https://blog.unity.com/technology/static-lighting-with-light-probes), etc.

=> after being processed (baked) the meshes are now combined into an overall static scene mesh and can not change their positions anymore!